# Custom JSONEncoder returns malformed Strings

Tags: python, string, json

I'm implementing my own JSONEncoder for handling different classes exactly as I need them. Unfortunately, my custom encoder returns somewhat malformed strings. They are surrounded by quotes and certain characters (quotes) are escaped.

Please use the following code to reproduce the behaviour:

```
import json

class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, givenObject):
        #for testing purposes this always returns the same string
        str = '{"id":0,"name":"Peter"}'
        return str;

class AnyClass(object):
    pass

encoder = CustomEncoder()
dummyClass = AnyClass()

#expected output: {"id":0,"name":"Peter"}
print encoder.encode(dummyClass)

#output: "{\"id\":0,\"name\":\"Peter\"}"
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

How can I prevent this behaviour? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default` should return an object, not a chunk of json:

```
import json

class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, givenObject):
        obj = {"id":0,"name":"Peter"}
        return obj

class AnyClass(object):
    pass

encoder = CustomEncoder()
dummyClass = AnyClass()

print encoder.encode(dummyClass) # {"id": 0, "name": "Peter"}
```

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default:

> Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns a serializable object for o, or calls the base implementation (to raise a TypeError).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I must have missed this part. I'm marking your answer as the right one because of the corrected code and the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    str = '{"id":0,"name":"Peter"}'
    return str;
```

try returning an object instead

```
    return {"id":0,"name":"Peter"}
```

As written, the library gets a string and encodes that to JSON by quoting it and escaping special characters.